# What process controls the menubar in OS X (not menuextras on the right side)?

Tags: macos, menu, osx-snow-leopard

I know menuextras are controlled by SystemUIServer. My question is what process controls the entire menubar, including accepting and displaying app menus on the left side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that would be WindowServer.